# Store file in S3 according to Year, month,date

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a very basic question.

The input is api feed from source, that has created date as a column. What I am looking to accomplish is to store this file(by splitting it up) into the following format:

landing/year=2020/month=01/date=01 and so on...
The year, month, date values are the dates from Created_at column.

THe file will be stored as transaction_id.parquet (transaction_id is also another column in the feed).

What is the suggested option to get to this structure? Is it prefix for each file by splitting created_date into year, month, date?

Looking for you response.

Thanks

Comment: The inclusion of "year=", "month=", and "date=" (I think you mean "day=") seems completely superfluous. I would propose either `landing/YYYY/MM/DD/` or `landing/YYYYMMDD/` as your prefix.

Comment: You appear to be wanting a format compatible with a partitioning structure, is this correct? If so, please include those details in your Question, including how you intend to _use_ the files. Also, please let us know the format of the incoming file -- is it a parquet file? Do you want the file contents modified in any way, or is your task merely to place the file in an appropriate directory without changing its contents? (You said "store this file by splitting it up", so it isn't too clear.)

Comment: By splitting the incoming API feed - we will query data from past 5 days. Once the data is recieved via API call to service, I would like to split them by day by month by year so that we have a proper warehouse for the records. I am looking for a way to partition the bucket so it is manageable. Incoming is from API request. I simply want to store them as is, I have a glue job consuming the data. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Your design should be something like below

- Create a file in YYYYMMDD format
- let's assume that you are receiving a file named 20220129file_name.txt
- Split it by "_" to get the DATE portion
- Split other parts such as year/month and day
- Create another function to validate if a particular year/month/day S3 folder exists? if yes then put the file in that folder or else create the folder set and put the file.
- There is no ready-made code for the same but you can create it. It's pretty simple.